# Increasing max-open files for Beanstalkd in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, beanstalkd

I'm not well know all beanstalkd tricks, and I need to increase max-open files for beanstalkd in our AWS EC2 instances. I found couple resources in internet(that looks more trusted for me), that suggest to change not only beanstalkd configurations, and system configurations like that:

```
# file: /etc/default/beanstalkd
BEANSTALKD_LISTEN_ADDR=127.0.0.1
BEANSTALKD_LISTEN_PORT=11300
START=yes
BEANSTALKD_EXTRA="-b /var/lib/beanstalkd -f 1"

# Should match your /etc/security/limits.conf settings
ulimit -n 100000
```

And explanation that why I should change "/etc/security/limits.conf" is:
"Lot's of resources online tell you to update your /etc/security/limits.conf and /etc/pam.d/common-session* settings to increase your maximum number of available file descriptors. However, the default beanstalkd installation on Ubuntu 12.04+ uses an init script that starts the daemon process using start-stop-daemon which does not use your system settings when setting the processes ulimits. Just add this line to your defaults and you're good to go!"

I don't want to change any global system settings. All I want is change beanstalkd settings.

So why i should make this changes if default beanstalkd installation on Ubuntu 12.04+ uses an init script that starts the daemon process using start-stop-daemon which does not use your system settings when setting the processes ulimits?
And if someone know better way to increasing max-open files for beanstalkd in AWS EC2 instance, without this changes in system settings?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Best resource, how to raising open files: https://underyx.me/2015/05/18/raising-the-maximum-number-of-file-descriptors